# Can't access HTTPS but can access HTTP for our website on server.

Tags: ssl, https, server, windows-server-2008-r2

We can't access the https:// version of our company website. (http:// is accessible).

We have looked at the certification, it is valid and working correctly. 
We have looked into the Bindings, it looks good.

On IE the error is: 
"This page can’t be displayed"

On Chrome the error is:
"This site can’t be reached"

Server Details:
Windows 2008 R2 sever.
IIS - Hosted Website

We suspect that the TLS disabled on the server might cause the problem. (What do you think?)

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the appropriate port (443) is open in the firewall?

Comment: Yes, did a "netstat -an" on CMD. 0.0.0.0:443 is listening.

Comment: @DanyalOzair: that only tells you that the process is listening, i.e. will respond to data in case it receives any. That does not tell you if the firewall on this system or some middleware in the path blocks access. It definitely looks like a firewall issue.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.

Firewall Inbound rules .
Web wide services (HTTPS Traffic-In) port 443 is allowed and enabled.

Comment: Hello, were you able to find the solution? I am facing the same issue :(